# How can I see where in my themes and plugins certain image sizes are used?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I've had the same WordPress blog for years upon years, and years ago, I installed the [Simple Image Sizes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-image-sizes/) plugin to control image sizes. I think I wanted an easy way to set the size of post header images.

I didn't document things well, though, so I added a bunch of image sizes and now, years and at least one theme change later, I don't have any idea where those image sizes I added are actually used in my site, if at all.

According to my Media page and the Simple Image Sizes plugin, in addition to thumbnail, medium, and large image sizes, I also have the following:

- post-thumbnail
- post-image
- post-image-cover
- image-thumb
- blog-thumb

I'd like to remove the unused image size definitions if possible, since they're causing massive storage bloat with each uploaded image, but I don't know which of them are unused.

More experienced WordPress admins: how would you go about locating where in plugin and theme files, if anywhere, those image sizes are used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use my text editor to do a find in folder for each image size, starting with `post-thumbnail`.  If non are found, then they aren't being used.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've changed the theme, you should stick to using theme's image sizes & remove the "Simple Image Sizes" plugin. This will ensure images are shown perfectly.

If you still intend to remove some of the sizes, in your theme's `functions.php` locate code similar to this.

`add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup' );
function setup() {
    // ...

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); // This feature enables post-thumbnail support for a theme
add_image_size( 'header', 600, 200, true ); // header image
add_image_size( 'custom-size1', 400, 200 ); // 400 pixel wide and 200 pixel tall, resized proportionally
add_image_size( 'custom-size2', 400, 200, true );// 400 pixel wide and 200 pixel tall, cropped

// ...
```

}`

Or search for `add_image_size` or `post-image-cover` in your theme's folder to locate & remove.